# get top 10 from database with some calculation

Tags: sql, mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `photos` (
  `p_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `u_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `p_date` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `p_content` longtext NOT NULL,
  `p_title` text NOT NULL,
  `p_photo` text NOT NULL,
  `p_small` text NOT NULL,
  `p_thumb` text NOT NULL,
  `p_up` bigint(20),
  `p_down` bigint(20),
  PRIMARY KEY  (`p_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=229 ;
```

And I want first 10 top rated photos!
But because there is p_up (thumb up) and p_down (thumb down)
Its kind complicated!
Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM photos ORDER BY (p_up-p_down) DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 2):

SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY p_up - p_down DESC LIMIT 10

Will be faster if you CREATE INDEX foo ON table ( p_up - p_down )

Answer (score 0):

Following query will fetch photos with biggest p_up - p_down value first:

```
select * from photos order by (p_up - p_down) desc;
```